# Pie diagram chart.js is not full

Tags: codeigniter, chart.js, diagram

I'm trying to make pie diagram using chart.js in codeigniter, but the pie diagram is not full, the middle is empty, only the edges that appear. how must i do?

[image: pie diagram]

Comment: Welcome to SO.It should be more clear about the question here so that you would get answers or help faster.So you can add your necessary codes here..

Comment: Presumably you are using `type: doughnut` when you should be using `type: pie`. For the record: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add your javascript pie chart code too..